# set or get Child Component properties inside Window.Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to set component TextBlock Text from code, I try to access it like `this.dialog.lbTitle.Text` but this cant access from code..

**Edit:**

```
CustomDialog dialog;
public async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{           
    this.dialog = (CustomDialog)this.Resources["CustomDialogTest"];
    //this.dialog.lbTitle.Text = "Haloo"; --> I like to do something like this
        this.dialog.Height = 500;
    await this.ShowMetroDialogAsync(dialog);
}
```

***XAML:***

```
...
xmlns:Dialog="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
...
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonOpacity" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Control.Opacity" Value="0.2"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Dialog:CustomDialog x:Key="CustomDialogTest"
                                x:Name="CustomTestDialog">

        <Grid Background="Beige" ShowGridLines="False">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Height="250" Source="/images/rumus.jpg" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="12" Margin="10,10,10,10" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="20" Text="Title:" />
            <TextBlock Name="lbTitle" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="20" Text="" />

        </Grid>
    </Dialog:CustomDialog>
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, you are not sharing the class "Dialog" by using partial class definition.
To look inside the FramworkElement's children, you can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dialog = (CustomDialog)this.Resources["CustomDialogTest"];

    // at this point ensure that "lbTitle" is instantiated and part of the dialogs visual tree
    var tb = dialog.FindName("lbTitle") as TextBlock;
    if(tb != null && dialog != null)
    {
        tb.Text = "Haloo"; --> I like to do something like this
    }
}
```

Comment: I instantiate in xaml, still cant accessible. xmlns:Dialog="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"

Comment: Hi, please see the edit above. If that does not point in the right direction, you may want to post a bit more code.

Comment: the tb is null,  can create like var tb = new TextBlock(); ?

Comment: OK, so my guess is that dialog, when retrieved by this.Resources["name"], does not represent the element of the visual tree. Another Guess: the dialog did not yet instantiate the TextBlock. Maybe You have a Create / Show function to be called first ?

Comment: yes I have create to called it.
but can use `style` to set `lbTitle.Text` value ? or use data binding ?

Comment: So to me it sounds plausible if you create your dialog first. please see the comment line in my suggested solution. There you should create the dialog. It should create its child elements then and your textBlock may be available. Using style or binding is more wpf-like, but that is a complete different solution, using MVVM

Comment: I instance `tb = new TextBlock();` before `tb = dialog.FindName("lbTitle") as TextBlock;` and same get null error.

Comment: If you instantiate the TextBlock in code, it is not part of the dialog. please create the dialog and verify the dialog's TextBlock is created. Or implement a dialog function that places "Haloo" in its TextBlock, and call this function in your click handler!